# SQL: How to know what value was matched in SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to return WHAT was matched when performing a SELECT query?

This is my SELECT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM user 
WHERE username = :username OR email = :email 
EXCEPT 
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM user 
WHERE username = :current_username OR email = :current_email
```

As you can see, I am checking if there is an existing user in table `user` based on entered username or email `EXCEPT` the same account as being logged in with.
So if I am logged in with username `foo` it will not find a match when I search for `foo` as username and so on...

So far so good! Now here is my question...

All I get is a number of matches from this SELECT. But how can I know if it was due to username or email being matched?

Thanks

Comment: You can't with that query. You could split this apart into multiple queries but honestly what are you trying to do here?

Comment: And Is that how `EXCEPT` works in sqlite?, I mean, the way I see it, it should return a `COUNT(*)` for the username unless the exact same `COUNT(*)` exists for the current username; not the `COUNT(*)` of one minus the other

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental conceptualization behind the way you've structured your query needs some tweaking. The answer isn't to find out which one matched but to change the query.

Specifically, using `EXCEPT` on the result of two `Count` queries is nonsensical. You don't want to match two different counts and show no result if they are equal, instead you really want the count *after* the `EXCEPT` has occurred, not before. That's not going far enough, yet, but I'll show you that in a moment.

So let's switch it around to see:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
   (
      SELECT username, email
      FROM user 
      WHERE username = :username OR email = :email 
      EXCEPT 
      SELECT username, email
      FROM user 
      WHERE username = :current_username OR email = :current_email
   ) AS X
;
```

However, this is unnecessarily complicated. You can do the same thing with a single `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
   (
      SELECT username, email
      FROM user 
      WHERE
         (
            username = :username
            OR email = :email 
         )
         AND username <> :current_username
         AND email <> :current_email
   ) AS X
;
```

But I would like to suggest that even this is probably not the query you need. Either there will always only be 1 row returned, in which case you don't truly need a count, or there could be multiple rows returned, in which case you need to see what was returned in order to inspect it more closely. If you get a count of 2, what will you do with that information? So.

If it can be guaranteed that exactly zero or one row will always be returned, then:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT username, email
   FROM user 
   WHERE
      (
         username = :username
         OR email = :email 
      )
      AND username <> :current_username
      AND email <> :current_email
);
```

But if multiple rows are possible, then:

```
SELECT username, email
FROM user 
WHERE
   (
      username = :username
      OR email = :email 
   )
   AND username <> :current_username
   AND email <> :current_email
;
```

With the information I have now, I don't think anything else makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT 'username' as "type", COUNT(*) 
FROM user 
WHERE username = :username AND username <> :current_username
UNION
SELECT 'email' as "type", COUNT(*) 
FROM user 
WHERE email = :email  AND email <> :current_email
```